# how to make an input group collapsed after finishing writing or when clicked anywhere?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a collapsed navbar on the outside clicking navbar element using bootstrap, and it worked

but when I megganti navbar element with input form, this is not the way I want
because when I would fill out the form navbar automatically collapse before I finished it

This is the code that I created: http://jsfiddle.net/acile/3cbje867/

HTML code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
<a type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Application</a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-search">
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav menu menu-main-menu">        
<li>
<div class="input-group">
    <input id="search-input" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="input-group-btn">           
        <button id="search-button" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
    </div>
</input>
</div>
</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

javascript code:

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
    var $navsearch = $(".navbar-search");
    var _opened = $navsearch.hasClass("in");

    if (_opened === true) {
        $navsearch.collapse('hide');
    }
});
```

help me please, how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to determine whether you are clicking inside of the element or not.

Use `$(e.target).closest($navsearch).length` to check whether the click event occurs inside of `$('.navbar-collapse.navbar-search')`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jof9tLkz/)

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var $navsearch = $('.navbar-collapse.navbar-search');
    if(!$(e.target).closest($navsearch).length && $navsearch.is(':visible')) {
        $navsearch.collapse('hide')
    }        
})
```

Comment: thanks @Josh Crozier after I made some changes to your code, it works for me,.

thank you very much,.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's navigation has already the collapsed functionality in-built so you don't have to re-write it. You could manually hide the search bit using some jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/1p8p0dnf/5/

```
$('#search-button').on('click', function() {

    // Remove collapsed class
    $('#search-nav').removeClass('in');

    // Clear search input text
    $('#search-input').val('');
});
```